# XMLHttpRequest Response empty in chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Hello I develop a chrome extension.
In my js script i want to make an XMLHttpRequest.
The php file is read by the script (i see it in the log of my wamp) but the xhr.status value is 0 and  the responseText is empty.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost/ss/test.php?tt='+tt, true);
xhr.responseType = 'text';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {            
        if(xhr.responseText=='a'){
            alert('a');
        }else if(xhr.responseText=='b'){
            alert('b');
        }else{
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    }else{
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

in the php file I just wrote echo "a";

Comment: Will you share anything shown in error console log in Chrome Developer Toolset?

Comment: I solved this problem. I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in the php file